# Use \ttfamily font systematically in examples

Tags: fonts, amsbook

My problem is as in the title: I want to use \ttfamily font *systematically in examples only*, inside \documentclass{amsbook}. I do this because I want to distinguish examples from the text around in this way.

The ideal way should be something like `\newtheorem{example}[thm]{Example}[\ttfamily]` (which doesn't work unfortunately).

Comment: `amsbook` uses (something similar to) `amsthm`, so you need to make your own theorem style and then activate that style before you run your `\newtheorem`, how to define a theorem style is explained in the manual for `amsthm`. Alternatively you can probably use the `thmtools` pacakge which gives an easier interface.

Comment: I didn't say that I used `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]` before `\newtheorem{example}[thm]{Example}, \newtheorem{theorem}[thm]{Theorem}`, which (works and) gives the same font for Theorems and Examples, but now I want Examples to have `\ttfamily` font.

Comment: That is not what I'm saying there is a `\theoremstyle` macro, you need to make an appropriate style for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and easy way is to bypass the 'official' command for defining a new theorem style (which is `\newtheoremstyle`) and define a style using the internal command `\th@somestyle` with only the font setting. This is similar to how for example the built-in `definition` style is defined in the source of `amsthm`.

Teletype normally has fixed width characters, so the lines are usually uneven. If you want justified text you can modify some of the font dimensions, see http://texblog.net/latex-archive/plaintex/full-justification-with-typewriter-font/.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\def\th@example{%
  \ttfamily % body font
  \fontdimen2\font=0.4em% interword space
  \fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
  \fontdimen7\font=0.1em% extra space
}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}[thm]{Example}

\begin{document}
This is an example:
\begin{example}
An example can be short, or long, such as an entire line this is repeated a few times.
An example can be short, or long, such as an entire line this is repeated a few times.
An example can be short, or long, such as an entire line this is repeated a few times.
\end{example}
This is a theorem:
\begin{thm}
P is either short or long.
A theorem can be long, such as an entire line this is repeated a few times.
A theorem can be long, such as an entire line this is repeated a few times.
A theorem can be long, such as an entire line this is repeated a few times.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now. But there is a problem: it looks very ugly, the length of lines in Examples are all different. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Lao-tzu that is normal with teletype (`ttfamily`) because all characters have the same width so spaces cannot be stretched like in a normal font. But it can be done, I'll post an edit.

Comment: I saw and tried, it works perfectly now. It seems `\theoremstyle{example}` here is very important, initially I didn't write it inside and it doesn't change anything. Many thanks!

Comment: @Lao-tzu `\newtheorem` copies the current style setting so yes the location of the style is rather important